# Firstore rules: fetch the roles of authenticated user to grant update access

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'd like to adapt my rules when updating a classifiedAd.

Currently only owner of the ad is granted to update as follows:

```js
 match /classifiedAds/{uid}/{document=**} {
   allow read, create: if true; 
   allow update, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.ownerId;
```

For moderation purpose, I'd like to add moderators to the update rules: they are the users (in collection users) that have "moderation" role as follows, but I don't know how to "join" with `users` collection on `id=uid`:

```js
 match /classifiedAds/{uid}/{document=**} {
   allow read, create: if true; 
   allow update: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.ownerId || <<request.auth.uid with resource.data.roles["moderation"] in users collection>>;  
   allow delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.ownerId;
```

How to write the rule `<<request.auth.uid with resource.data.roles["moderation"] in users collection>>>` ?

[UPDATE]

I tried this without success, I still have `PERMISSION_DENIED`:

```js
// === ClassifiedAds
match /classifiedAds/{uid}/{document=**} {
   
  // Get the user using uid
    function getUser() {
    return get(/databases/{database}/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data;
  }

        allow read, create: if true; 
  allow update: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.ownerId || getUser().roles["moderation"];  
  allow delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.ownerId;  

}
```

Also, how can I log those rules?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the issue, as there was a typo in the document path in the `getUser()` function.

The working code's as follows:

```
    // === Get the user using uid
    function getUser() {
      return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data;
    }
      
    // === ClassifiedAds
    match /classifiedAds/{uid}/{document=**} {
      allow read, create: if true; 
      allow update: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.ownerId || getUser().roles["moderation"];  
      allow delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.ownerId;  
    }
```